# Resampling xarray DataSet using different methods

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

I need to resample a `DataSet` using `mean()` for one, `sum()` for another data variable. I am using this somewhat cumbersome method:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

airtemps = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
airtemps = airtemps.sel(time=slice('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'))
airtemps['air'] = airtemps.air - 273.15
airtemps['data'] = (('time', 'lat', 'lon'), np.random.random(airtemps.air.shape))

dataSummed = airtemps.data.resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
airtemps_month = airtemps.resample('M', dim='time', how='mean')
airtemps_month['data_summed'] = dataSummed
```

Can/should this be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a collection of `DataArrays` which in `xarray` is called a `Dataset`. So resample each `DataArray` on its own and construct a new dataset.  Many ways to do this, here's one:

```
In [22]: ds = airtemps.air.resample('M', dim='time', how='mean').to_dataset()

In [23]: ds['data_summed'] = airtemps.data.resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')

In [24]: ds
Out[24]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (lat: 25, lon: 53, time: 12)
Coordinates:
  * lat          (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 62.5 60.0 57.5 55.0 ...
  * lon          (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 210.0 212.5 215.0 ...
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31 ...
Data variables:
    air          (time, lat, lon) float64 -28.68 -28.49 -28.48 -28.67 -28.99 ...
    data_summed  (time, lat, lon) float64 63.47 66.98 63.67 65.82 61.17 ...
```

Comment: `airtemps` already is a DataSet so I hoped I could get around creating a copy of it but it's 50% faster than my way. In pandas one would `groupby` and aggregate `grouped.agg({'data': np.sum, 'airt': np.mean})` which is more concise. However `how` in `resample()` is deprecated in pandas and it would raise a `FutureWarning`. It's honestly not the answer I was looking for, but it might be the only one!

Comment: @TomTom101, As you note, the xarray doesn't let you use the `.agg` syntax you mention. The resample already requires a copy and you wouldn't want to put the resampled dataarrays back in the same dataset since the time dimensions would be different. You are going to want to datasets here anyway you shake it.